# XCode7 debug on AppleWatch Slow

Tags: debugging, ios9, watchkit, xcode7, watchapp

After I installed XCode7 I have a lot of problems to debug a WatchApp on real device (watchOS2). Even if the App is very very simple (on button only) Xcode take a lot of time to deploy the App on Apple watch and start debug. Someone with the same problem?
I'm using Xcode 7.01, WatchOS2 and iOS9.02 on iPhone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After unpaired and paired again the Watch I solved the problem